# Помогите с датой

Tags: javascript, дата

Почему при вводе этого значения, у меня получается другая дата. Вводится 2020, 12, 12 выводится, 2021 01 12

```
console.log("props of day", props.weekDay) //props of day 12.12.2020
    const dateSplit = props.weekDay.split(".")
    console.log("dateSplit is ", dateSplit) //dateSplit is  (3) ["12", "12", "2020"]
    const dayOfWeek = new Date(dateSplit[2], dateSplit[0], dateSplit[1])
    console.log("dayOfWeek is ", dayOfWeek) //dayOfWeek is  Tue Jan 12 2021
```

Comment: Месяц индексируется с нуля

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я уже написал в комментарии: **месяц индексируется с нуля**.
Вот [ссылка](https://learn.javascript.ru/date) про Date, где можно об этом почитать.

Также проблему можно решить, передав в конструктор не отдельные значения, а строку, предварительно заменив точки на дефисы и изменив порядок.

```
const dateString = '12.12.2020'; // day, month, year
const [day, month, year] = dateString.split('.');

const newDateString = [year, month, day].join('-');
const date = new Date(newDateString);
console.log(date); // 2020-12-12T00:00:00.000Z
```

Еще можно заменить регуляркой:

```
const dateString = '12.12.2020'; // day, month, year
const newDateString = dateString.replace(/^(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{4})/,'$3-$2-$1'); // 2020-12-12
const date = new Date(newDateString);
```

Comment: спасибо большое:)

Comment: @bazmexes пожалуйста)